# Dupehammering mistagged questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Let me start this with the situation I faced today and a few times before. I am very active with the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag and I recently closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49386592/making-part-of-span-text-as-bold-is-not-working) as duplicate BUT this question has nothing to do with CSS (the tag is irrelevant here) and it's mainly related to jQuery and I was able to close it simply because I am experienced with jQuery and I know there is a dup for it.

I know there is no issue since it was done correctly but I was able to do it only because the user added an irrelevant tag where I had a gold badge. I was also sure it will be done by a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) gold owner if I didn't do it.

Considering this, I thought about two possible ways in which the behavior of the dupehammer might be changed, to make it more accurate.

### I. Adding more restriction

In the first case, I would consider a restriction based on **the other question**. A user can close a question as a duplicate only if the chosen question contains also the tag where he has a gold badge, so the tag should be present in both questions. In such situation, I won't be able to close the above one since I don't have the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) gold.

I know this may seem useless as we have the responsibility to choose the right question as a dup depending on its content and not its tags. We also know that some users don't specify the correct tags and this restriction will decrease the power of the dupe hammer especially for tags that are very close and are always mixed in the wrong way.

On the other hand this can useful for other reasons:

- This will force us to correctly edit well known and common questions with the relevant tags.
- This will make the duplicate process more accurate and we avoid bad behavior such as closing a [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) question with a [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) one and we end with a bad duplicate.

### II. Adding more flexibility

This situation is based on the fact that new users don't correctly specify the relevant tags.

Let's take a simple example:

A user is asking a question related to CSS but he only used the [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag. The question is very common and has a clear duplicate but I cannot close is as I don't have the gold for [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3). We were able to do this previously by editing and adding the missing tag but it was removed as it can lead to abusive behavior.

In such case, why we don't allow a user with gold [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) to close as a duplicate if **the chosen question** contains the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag? In other words, we can close as duplicate if the tag is present in the question and if it's not it needs to be present in the question he considers as the duplicate one.

I know this may also lead to some abusive behavior but we can also consider some restrictions (for example: if a user edited a question to include the tag he can no more use it to close as duplicate).

**Why this can be useful?**

Because it will allow us to easily handle new *bad* questions where only **one** *bad* tag is specified (or many tags and missing relevant ones) and where it's clear that the question need to be closed as a duplicate. This situation will give more powerful to gold badge owner but if used well it will allow us to avoid clear duplicate question being answered and/or closed very late.

---

**UPDATE**

As commented below, my intention is not to consider both cases at the same time that's why I split them. The idea is either to add more restriction(I) or to add more flexibility(II).

***As a side note***: I am not complaining about the dupehammer process, I simply want to share some ideas. I know that even if we cannot directly close a question we can flag, comments and it will simply take more time and will get closed by the 5 voting process. The idea behind this is to consider few cases where the closing process can be restricted to avoid bad behavior or can be made faster.

Comment: Wait. Do you mean that, nonwithstanding any kind of relevance, a css gold badge owner (in your second option) could close a c++ question as duplicate of a css question *because they have gold on the target duplicate*?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier `could close a c++ question as duplicate of a css question because they have gold on the target question?` --> yes true if it's bad used, but logically you should not do this ... that's why i said **if used well** :)

Comment: I feel like both your points are contradictory. On one you say you shouldn't have dupehammer unless the dupe target ALSO has the tag... And on point two you basically say that the tags of the question shouldn't matter...

Comment: @Patrice because both point are different .. my intention wasn't to consider them both together ... to consider only one situation at a time. So adding more restriction or adding more flexibility, but both together was not my intention

Comment: I don't quite have the time right now to write a proper answer, but I sense a lack of trust on the behalf of gold-badge holders.  There are few enough of us that managing this at this scale isn't a big deal, and abuse is fairly straightforward to identify and fix.

Comment: About the first point: The OpenGL community closes OpenGL&C++ questions quite often as duplicates of C++ only questions. Since a lot of C++ regulars avoid questions with OpenGL tag, closing such questions would get way harder. I guess the same situation applies to almost all library/framework related tags where closing with language only quesitons is relevant.

Comment: @Makoto, there is no lack of trust as myself am gold-bagde holders and each day i handle/ close many question and reopen them if needed

Comment: *"the tag should be present in both questions"* This would prevent most users from using popular [tag:language-agnostic] questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/2301450) one) as their hammer targets

Comment: @Temami that makes sense. I thought you were asking for both and I got confused. Thx